# Error number 13 - Remote access svn with dav_svn failing

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, ubuntu

I'm getting the following error on my svn repository

```
<D:error>
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="13">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

I've followed the instructions from the [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/), and the [Ubuntu Community Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion), but to no success.  I've even given the repository `777` permissions.

```
<Location /svn/myProject >

  # Uncomment this to enable the repository
  DAV svn

  # Set this to the path to your repository
  SVNPath /svn/myProject
  # Comments

  # Comments

  # Comments
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  # More Comments

</Location>
```

The permissions follow:

```
drwxrwsrwx 6 www-data webdev 4096 2010-02-11 22:02 /svn/myProject
```

And `svnadmin` validates the directory

```
$svnadmin verify /svn/myProject/
* Verified revision 0.
```

and I'm accessing the repository at

```
http://ipAddress/svn/myProject
```

Edit: The apache error log says

```
[Fri Feb 12 13:55:59 2010] [error] [client <ip>] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/svn/myProject/format': Permission denied
[Fri Feb 12 13:55:59 2010] [error] [client <ip>] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Fri Feb 12 13:55:59 2010] [error] [client <ip>] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #13]
[Fri Feb 12 13:55:59 2010] [error] [client <ip>] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #13]
```

Even though I confirmed that this file is ugo readable and writable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to give permissions to apache to the directory above my repo: ie `/svn`

I used the command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:webdev /svn
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the permissions of the files and subdirectories in /svn/myProject weren't changed. Did you change them recursively?

Comment: I just double checked, and re-ran recursive.  No change.